# Pyplot start x axis at negative values

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a piecewise function, but at the moment I am getting an error message when I try to start my x values at a negative. The code works fine if I run the following (albeit with only one part of the function):

```
x = np.linspace(0, 100, 100)
y = np.piecewise(x, [x < 0, x >= 0], [0, (1/100)*x*np.exp(-x/10)])
z = -np.exp(-x/10)*((x/10)+1)+1
plt.plot(x, y, 'r', label='test')
plt.legend(loc='right')
plt.show()
```

But when I change the first line to

```
x = np.linspace(-100, 100, 100)
```

I get thrown the error message: "NumPy boolean array indexing assignment cannot assign 100 input values to the 50 output values where the mask is true"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the examples provided in the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.piecewise.html):

```
y = np.piecewise(x, [x < 0, x >= 0], [0, lambda x: (1/100)*x*np.exp(-x/10)])
```

Output:

[image]